# Struts - how can i get value of an select list if its empty?

Tags: java, html, struts

I have an issue with a array object in ActionForm that's displayed as "Select" element in HTML, and the user can add and remove options, and then when submitting i add or remove the values in the database, all works properly, i select all options when submitting so all values will be mapped in the array of the form, and so on.

but, when the user submits an empty select, i didn't see any changes in the form object, the form didn't recognize that the value of that array is null.

I'm using struts 1.2

Comment: When the user submits an empty select, the browser does not post anything for that item so no setter is called on the form bean.  It is the same behaviour as if your select did not appear on the form at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nothing is selected, then the array will stay as it was when the form bean was instantiated. So if you initialize it to an empty array, you'll have what you want.

My guess is that you're using the (unfortunate) default session scope for your form beans. It's a bad practice. You should prefer request-scoped form beans. And if you really want to stay with session-scoped form beans, then they should override the reset() method in order to reset the properties to their default values before being populated from the request parameters.

Comment: Thanks JB, You are the best.<br/>I Found i way hoe to notify the struts form that the array is empty. i remove this select from his parent node, and created a new element with that name as the select, and i check in the action if that array[0].isEmpty() then assign null to that object.